# Re-grant user permissions for LinkedIn not working

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

There's a major issue in LinkedIn OAuth2 flow for external application **Grant Access**.

If user remove the external application grant access from their app settings and grant the access again after authentication then **MyApp** settings will not show the external application anymore.

**Reproduce the issue:**

- *Step1:* Remove the granted access for any external application from MyApps under settings page - https://www.linkedin.com/secure/settings
- *Step2:* Authenticate again for the same deleted external application using the LinkedIn account credentials and grant the access for requested permissions.
- *Step3:* Refresh the page mentioned in Step1. You'll not see the external application with grant permissions.

**Note:**

You'll get the access token in second authentication attempt without any issues but all other API callbacks will be failed using the new access token with below error:

```
401
{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Then token used in this request has been revoked by the user.",
  "requestId": "HWZ5X8TVSH",
  "status": 401,
  "timestamp": 1466526549077
}
```

Tested with other social networks such as Facebook and it's working perfectly fine.

Comment: Would you mind cleaning up the cookies/cached sessions via code and then ask for re-authentication, it should work then?

Comment: @RenoJones - Is there any expiry threshold set for it? I have tried with chrome-incognito new session and it worked after few attempts for both curl REST API callback and browser.

Comment: Uh oh, i don't have much information about the expiry threshold they have. But it's a common behavior, these OAuth based APIs are based on sessions/cache of cookies.

Comment: @RenoJones - I've asked LinkedIn support team to basically give some heads up on expiry threshold. But apart from that everything seems to be working! Thanks for your help.

Comment: No Problem, as long as the problem is solved, we're good. :)